# OpenShift 3: Connect Java Webapp to PostgreSQL Database

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, openshift

I have a **Tomcat 8** web app running on **OpenShift 3**.

I also have a **PostgreSQL** pod running, I can see it in the **Web Console**.

There is one table in the database that has three rows of data.

**Now I want to connect the Java web app to the database.**

I have trawled through heaps of documentation but I have not found an example of how to do this.

**Anyone out there got any pointers or examples or advice?** Anything to help...

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the right JDBC url to your java application.

Below are the Environment Var. for POSTGRE SQL in OS 3:

- Username: POSTGRESQL_USER
- Password: $POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD
- Database: $POSTGRESQL_DATABASE

Reference
https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/using_images/db_images/postgresql.html

Comment: Thanks but I know about the variables and I am an experienced Java web programmer who has built several OpenShift v2 database driven web applications. But I have not worked with containers. I would like to see an example of connecting to the database inside its pod.

Comment: For example: String postgresqlDatabase = System.getenv("POSTGRESQL_DATABASE"); does NOT get the database name. There's more to it than that...

Comment: Have you got a terminal inside of the pod and run ``env`` to validate that the environment variables are being passed in? If you run ``oc set env --list`` against the deployment configuration for your application, are you seeing the environment variables even set in the deployment configuration.

Comment: Yes and I get the following 
oc set env pod/postgresql-1-l14s1 --list
# pods postgresql-1-l14s1, container postgresql
# POSTGRESQL_USER from secret postgresql, key database-user
# POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD from secret postgresql, key database-password
POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=testdb

But how do I get the actual user and password from the secrets and also, how to connect using java?

Comment: I have also used oc to run sql on the database using psql. Everything is in place to progress my testbed program but I just don't see examples of the actual connection in Java...

Comment: OK, I can now connect to the database from my webapp but NOT using the environment variables from the postgresql pod. I will start a new question to address the actual problem of getting the values...

Comment: could you please share the question which you have mentioned in above